# Can't Backpropagate in Pytorch module with .backwards(); weights are not updated

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm willing to create a network estimating the next sample of the signal. I've statred with a simple sin signal. But when I run the code I got noise as an output. Then checked the layer weights and figured aout that they are not updating. I can't find the mistake here.

```
class Model(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,in_dim,hidden_dim,num_classes):
    super(Model, self).__init__()
    self.layer1 = nn.Linear(in_dim,hidden_dim)
    self.layer2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim,hidden_dim)
    self.layer3 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim,num_classes)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()

def forward(self,x):
    a = self.relu(self.layer1(x))
    a = self.relu(self.layer2(a))
    return self.relu(self.layer3(a))
```

train:

```
def train(epoch,L,depth):
    criteria = nn.MSELoss()
    learning_rate = 1e-3
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

    t = np.linspace(0,2,L+2)       
    fs = L+2

    trn_loss = list()

   for f in range(0,epoch):
       phase = f/np.pi      
       x = np.sin(2*np.pi*t*fs+phase)   
       x = torch.from_numpy(x).detach().float()

       optimizer.zero_grad()

       x_hat = model(x[:-2])

       currentCost = criteria(x_hat,x[-2])
       trn_loss.append(currentCost.item())
       print(model.layer1.weight.data.clone())
       currentCost.backward()
       optimizer.step()
       print(model.layer1.weight.data.clone())
       sys.exit('DEBUG')
```

output:

```
tensor([[-0.1715, -0.1696,  0.0424,  ...,  0.0154,  0.1450, -0.0544],
    [ 0.0368,  0.1427, -0.1419,  ...,  0.0966,  0.0298, -0.0659],
    [-0.1641, -0.1551,  0.0570,  ..., -0.0227, -0.1426, -0.0648],
    ...,
    [-0.0684, -0.1707, -0.0711,  ...,  0.0788,  0.1386,  0.1546],
    [ 0.1401, -0.0922, -0.0104,  ..., -0.0490,  0.0404,  0.1038],
    [-0.0604, -0.0517,  0.0715,  ..., -0.1200,  0.0014,  0.0215]])
tensor([[-0.1715, -0.1696,  0.0424,  ...,  0.0154,  0.1450, -0.0544],
    [ 0.0368,  0.1427, -0.1419,  ...,  0.0966,  0.0298, -0.0659],
    [-0.1641, -0.1551,  0.0570,  ..., -0.0227, -0.1426, -0.0648],
    ...,
    [-0.0684, -0.1707, -0.0711,  ...,  0.0788,  0.1386,  0.1546],
    [ 0.1401, -0.0922, -0.0104,  ..., -0.0490,  0.0404,  0.1038],
    [-0.0604, -0.0517,  0.0715,  ..., -0.1200,  0.0014,  0.0215]])
```

Comment: network seems to be ok, maybe it not backtracked because of  detach in torch.from_numpy(x).detach().float()

Comment: does input need to be backtracked?

Comment: i was wrong, it does learn for me.tensor([[-0.0673, -0.0288,  0.0291, tensor([[-0.0673, -0.0278,  0.0301, - small gradiend change. printout value of currentCost.items() -> it is your loss.

Comment: @kubicwerke input does not need to be backtracked (and usually isn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final layer in `forward` call uses `ReLU` activation. This limits outputs of the network to `[0, +inf)` range.

Please notice your target is in the `[-1, 1]` range, so the network **cannot output half (negative) of the values** (and for the positive part it has to crunch `+inf` possible values into `[0, 1]` space).

You should change `return self.relu(self.layer3(a))` to `return self.layer3(a)` in `forward`.

Better yet, in order to help your network accommodate to `[-1, 1]` range, use `torch.tanh` activation, so `return torch.tanh(self.layer3(a))` should work best.